# How to set ID and Text in html.label helper in mvc2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to set ID and Text attribute in html.label helper in mvc2

```
<%:html.label<have to set ID and Text properties here>%>
```

Plz help me out..

Comment: `<%:Html.Label("id","text")%>`

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: The [html label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/label) has only a FOR attribute, do you mean you want to use an html input instead?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Html.Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310185(v=vs.98).aspx) method returns an HTML `label` element and the property name of the property that is represented by the specified expression. For example:

### ASPX Syntax

```
<%: Html.Label("Text Content", new { id = "labelId" })%>
```

### Razor Syntax

```
@Html.Label("Text Content", new { id = "labelId" })
```

The second parameter is the htmlAttributes, so, you can add any html attribute you want as a property of this anonymous object. For example:

`new { id = "id-element", name = "name-element", size = 10, @class = "css-class" }`

### IdFor

If you want to take the `Id` by a html helper method, try to use:

```
@Html.IdFor(model => model.Property)
```