# Programatically change value based on selected item from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm still getting used to changing over from asp.net to asp.net mvc and I know that it doesn't use on action commands but I'm trying to change the text of a label based on when a user selects an item from a dropdownlist. I'm really not sure where to start :(

Comment: change text of a label when user select an item - could be easily be done with some jQuery

Comment: So you want to know his to do this in mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get this done using some jQuery, here I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AAAj/) for you.

Below is how you HTML should look like, incase you are using pure HTML in your views or even if you are using `@Html.LabelFor` or `@Html.DropDownListFor`

**HTML**

```
<label id="myLabel">Select a fruit:</label>
<select id="fruitSelector">
    <option val="">None</option>
    <option val="apple">apple</option>
    <option val="orange">orange</option>
    <option val="mango">mango</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#fruitSelector").change(function(){
    $("#myLabel").text("Fruit has been selected");
});
```

**Related help**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16828702/1182982
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14606324/1182982

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple example using jquery

```
 @Html.DropDownList("State", ViewBag.StateName as SelectList, 
"Select a State",
 new { id = "State" })

<label id="lbl1"></label>

<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function () {
        $('#State').change(function () {
            $('#lbl1').text($('#State').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
<label id="item">Selected Item: </label>
<select id="selector">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="JS">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="aspnet">Asp.net</option>
    <option value="mvc">Asp.Net MVC</option>
</select>
<label id="result"></label>

$("#selector").change(function()
{
    $("#result").text($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PLbnS/

Comment: Hope this helps you with your problem

Answer (score 0):

To start with, your `aspx` should look like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="myListDropDown" 
                CssClass="text" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myListDropDown_Change" />
```

And your code-behind file:

```
private void myListDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
                //put your code here
        }
```

Comment: I'm using asp.net mvc and this is asp.net code so it won't work I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

Write this code in your **SelectedValueChanged Event**  of dropdownlist :-

```
 private void dropdownlist_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                dropdownlist.Items["abc"]=label.text;
                dropdownlist.Items["xyz"]=label.text;

        }
```

Comment: I'm using asp.net mvc and it doesn't allow for comboboxes :(

Comment: you can just change combobox to dropdownlist