# JQuery label change understanding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to understand why the first JQuery line does NOT change the label text but the second JQuery line DOES.  Thoughts?

```
@Html.Label("lblTestLabel", "Old value I want replaced")


<script type="text/jscript">

    function PopulateTradeStats(result)
    {        
        $("#lblTestLabel").text('ThisWayDoes_NOT_Work');

        $("label[for='lblTestLabel']").text("ThisWayWorks!");       
    }

</script>
```

Comment: because 2nd one overwriting the 1st one? What is your HTML rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not ASP developer but seems like `@Html.Label("lblTestLabel", "Old value I want replaced")` only create a label with `for` attribute.

OUTPUT: `<label for="lblTestLabel">Old value I want replaced</label>`

You would need do like this for the first to work

```
@Html.Label("Old value I want replaced", new { id = "lblTestLabel", for = "lblTestLabel" })
```

OUTPUT: `<label id="lblTestLabel" for="lblTestLabel">Old value I want replaced</label>`

However that would be a bad idea since presumably your also using `@Html.TextBox("lblTestLabel")` or a similar `HtmlHelper` method to generate a form control for the associated property which would generate invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) and mean that any javascript to select the form control would not work

**Also make sure the id `lblTestLabel` is unique**, since `$("#lblTestLabel")` will only return the 1st match (if you have more than 1 element with the same id)

see example below:

```js
function PopulateTradeStats(result) {
  $("#lblTestLabel").text('ThisWayDoes_NOT_Work');

  /* $("label[for='lblTestLabel']").text("ThisWayWorks!"); */
}
PopulateTradeStats();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="lblTestLabel" for="lblTestLabel">Old value I want replaced No.1</label>
<br>
<label id="lblTestLabel" for="lblTestLabel">Old value I want replaced No.2</label>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have added, I do comment-out one out at a time. When I do that, the first way does not work and the second one does.  Everything I read, both should work.

Comment: @KeelRisk what is your HTML? does your label have an id that is unique?

Comment: Here is the HTML: <label for="lblTestLabel">Old value I want replaced</label>

Comment: @KeelRisk there is no id attribute at all, no way you can select an element.

Comment: @KeelRisk just call `console.log($("#lblTestLabel"))` all you will get is `undefined`

Comment: @KeelRisk take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605567/how-to-set-id-and-text-in-html-label-helper-in-mvc2

Comment: The best I can tell the $(#'lblTestLabel') is looking for 'id' while the $("label[for='lblTestLabel']") is using the 'for' and of course in the HTML the 'for' is there.  Asp.net mvc html.helpers for labels natively add the 'for' and not the 'id'.  My only guess

Comment: @KeelRisk yes, try `@Html.Label("Old value I want replaced", new { id = "lblTestLabel", for = "lblTestLabel" })`

Comment: Hey Daniel H...I did what you said about adding an id.  That confirmed, I was then able to change the value. So, long story short, when using mvc html helper Label there is only the 'for' and not 'id' then you must update accordingly. Thank for your help

Comment: This is not correct. The first one does not work because there is no `<label>` with `id="lblTestLabel"`. The `@Html.Label()` method does not add an `id` attribute to the element. It adds a `for` attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right, I add that in my comment for OP, I will update the post too, thanks!

Comment: Ping me when you do so I can remove the down-vote :)

Comment: Have edited it further to explain why you should not use `new { id="lblTestLabel" }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke nice, thanks again, I was here for jQuery, turns out it is ASP.NET, I'm trying hard! :D

Answer (score 0):

Both ways surely works!

**Unless** you have another element in your DOM with that same id `lblTestLabel`, and I guess you have your `<input id="lblTestLabel" ...>`

Then when you call `$("#lblTestLabel").text('ThisWayDoes_NOT_Work');` a selection for ID attribute always return just a single element, then it is trying to change a text from another element instead the one you wanted.

While this code `$("label[for='lblTestLabel']").text("ThisWayWorks!");` is looking for a label that is pointing to an lblTestLabel element and it will works every time.

Comment: I just searched the code and now the HTML view source and there is only one label with that id/for

Comment: what I'm guessing is that you have any other element instead of label with that same id, an <input> or <div> maybe. Ctrl+u in your resulting page and paste it to us in your question.

Comment: No, The first one does not work because there is no `<label>` element with `id="lblTestLabel"`

Answer (score 0):

Thats because @Html.Label(..) creates output as:

```
<label for="lblTestLabel">Old value I want replaced</label>
```

There is no id attribute in generated HTMl string.
you have add id as html attribute paramter in html helper to make this work.

```
e.g. @Html.Label("..", new {id = "LabelID"})
```